# Compiling a list of files with many directories

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

i've been banging my head over this issue today.

I have many c files in many directories. They all need to be compiled and linked to a library.

Here is a hypothetical layout of the files:

```
main_dir/
  thing1/
    thing1.c
  thing2/
    thing2.c
  thing3/
    thing3.c
MakeFile
```

I have a makefile that "finds" these files and generates the necessary objects, however, the same c file is always used as the input.

This is what the Makefile looks like (the contents of each file are a function each that uses puts()):

```
C=gcc
CFLAGS=-Wall -g
OBJDIR=obj
SRC=$(shell find src/ -type f -name "*.c")
SRC_DIRS=$(shell find src/ -type f -name "*.c" -exec dirname {} \; | uniq)
OBJS=$(SRC:%.c=${OBJDIR}/%.o)    

$(OBJS) : $(SRC)
    @echo Compiling : $<
    $(C) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -fv $(OBJS) thingy.a

folders:
    $(call build_dirs)

all: folders $(OBJS)
    ar -r -o thingy.a $(OBJS)

define build_dirs
    for dir in $(SRC_DIRS); do \
        mkdir -pv $(OBJDIR)/$$dir; \
    done
endef
```

The output from making:

```
for dir in src/thing1 src/thing2 src/thing3; do mkdir -pv obj/$dir; done
Compiling : src/thing1/thing1.c
gcc -c -Wall -g -o obj/src/thing1/thing1.o src/thing1/thing1.c
Compiling : src/thing1/thing1.c
gcc -c -Wall -g -o obj/src/thing2/thing2.o src/thing1/thing1.c
Compiling : src/thing1/thing1.c
gcc -c -Wall -g -o obj/src/thing3/thing3.o src/thing1/thing1.c
ar -r -o thingy.a obj/src/thing1/thing1.o obj/src/thing2/thing2.o obj/src/thing3/thing3.o
ar: creating thingy.a
```

I'm very certain the problem is my use of $(SRC) in
   $(OBJS) : $(SRC)
However, I just don't know what to do.

Anybody with MakeFu that could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $(OBJS) seems to be setup correctly, therefore the following should work (instead of $(OBJ) : $(SRC) target):

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    @echo Compiling : $<
    $(C) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: But then there is no rule for the objects

`make: *** No rule to make target 'obj/src/thing1/thing1.o', needed by 'all'. Stop.`

Comment: @regomodo Sorry, missed the fact that your objs were going in a different directory.

Comment: Thanks, that replaces a lot of my rules.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about the `$(OBJS)` rule being the problem.

Look at the variables: `(SRC)` is `src/thing1/thing1.c src/thing2/thing2.c src/thing3/thing3.c`, and `$(OBJS)` is `obj/src/thing1/thing1.o obj/src/thing2/thing2.o obj/src/thing3/thing3.o`. (Are you sure you want a `src` directory in `obj/`?) Now suppose you want to build `obj/src/thing2/thing2.o` using this rule:

```
$(OBJS) : $(SRC)
    @echo Compiling : $<
    $(C) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

The prerequisite field (`$(SRC)`) expands to "**src/thing1/thing1.c** src/thing2/thing2.c src/thing3/thing3.c", so `$<` expands to "**src/thing1/thing1.c**". Obviously what you want in this case is "**src/thing2/thing2.c**", so that's what the prerequisite field should be. What you need is something like a [pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules) or [static pattern rule](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Pattern). The trick is that you don't know the paths ahead of time, and Make doesn't handle patterns well, so we have to be deft:

```
$(OBJS) : $(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    @echo Compiling : $<
    $(C) -c $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had to remove the `$(OBJS)` from the rule to make it work.